# How to prevent Svelte triggering reactive changes when the value hasn't changed?

Tags: reactive-programming, svelte

In [this example](https://svelte.dev/repl/f5dbb0fac508466f820ee4eeef13a2b2?version=3.55.1), `someValue` is assigned the result of a ternary expression.

Regardless of whether `someIndex` is used, it is triggering reactive change to `someValue` when I don't want it to.

Is there any way to only trigger reactive changes to `someValue` if both `someIndex` changes *and* `someBool` is false?

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from "svelte";
    export let someBool = true;
    
    const someArray = [];
    const someObject = {};
    
    let someIndex = 0;
    let timesReacted = 0;
    
    $: someValue = someBool ? someObject : someArray[someIndex];
    $: someValue, timesReacted += 1;
        
    onMount(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => someIndex += 1, 1000);
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    });
</script>

someValue reacted to changes {timesReacted} times
```

Comment: If you rely on reactive variables *not* being updated arbitrarily often, you are probably using them the wrong way.

Comment: I don't think my requirement is "arbitrarily often". I don't want the reactive variable to update if its value hasn't changed. In this case, someObject is a constant so I don't want to trigger reactivity of someValue because its value hasn't changed.

Comment: If the value hasn't changed the update should not matter, that's my whole point.

Comment: In my case, the change has the side effect of calling video.load() because someValue is a list of sources for a video HTML tag. Because of this, it does matter in my case because of the side effect.

Comment: And that is why you are using it wrong: Side effects that should only happen a limited amount of times.

Comment: I agree with Chris, reactions when there is no value change can be costly - like firing an expensive database query when unnecessary.

Comment: @PaulW: For the most part one should keep state and actions/transactions separate. If state changes cause side effects that can also be an issue in understanding the code and tracking why things happen. Loading data is usually triggered by a user interaction, i.e. an event, not some hard to reason about state change.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the distinction. If I have a complex SPA where a change at the top triggers data reloads in multiple descendent components, how would that be triggered other than through reactive props? For example, in my app (a database monitoring tool), the user can drill down from a schema to a table, for example. That's a new entity, and there are various components that display that entity in different ways. All those components formerly showing schema-level info now have to show table-level info. Reactive props passed down to them carry the change. Is this wrong?

Comment: The triggering action would be a user click/navigation, everything that follows is usually just data flowing through the components *without* side effects. Sometimes the distinction is a bit hard to make but generally it's about idempotence in an immediate sense. E.g. if a change causes a spinner that *eventually* leads to the same page being displayed the immediate outcome for the user is still different hence something like that has to be managed carefully. Usually that is not even that hard to do because you pass around IDs which are primitives, which are equality checked more strictly.

Comment: Do you have a link to some blog or document that explains all this?

Comment: @PaulW: Sorry, i do not; this is just based on personal experience. Also, I am not saying that you are wrong, just that certain things are more error prone and maybe not the best approach to a given situation. Some complexity can be necessary to deliver the best user experience. I would evaluate things on a case by case basis on questions like: How much indirection is there? How much mutable state? How much asynchrony? Each of those aspects increase the risk of errors, so I would try to minimize that as much as reasonably possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
let someValue, lastSomeIndex

$: if (!someBool && someIndex !== lastSomeIndex) {
  someValue = someArray[someIndex]
  lastSomeIndex = someIndex
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes! A few small syntax tweaks needed but this works great. :-)